# CanGoBack always returns false for NavigationWindow

Tags: wpf, navigation, back-stack

I'm working on a project in WPF. I have a NavigationWindow and navigate between pages in this way:

```
SamplePage page = new SamplePage();
_window.Navigate(page);
```

It works fine and I can go back and forward with the navigation bar of the window. But I've noticed that the `CanGoBack` property is always false and the `BackStack` is always empty.

What might the problem be? I really need your help on this.

Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Apparently `_window.Navigate(page);` doesn't use the navigation history.  Note
that if navigation history is shared by multiple navigators (NavigationWindow, Frame), the most recent entry in back navigation history may not have been added by the NavigationService for the current navigator.

Comment: What must I do then?

Comment: Is navigation history being shared by multiple navigators?

Comment: I'm not sure actually. I have only one _window.Navigate(page) line of code in the whole project so I don't think the navigation history is shared anywhere else. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should read [this](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation).  It goes over WPF navigation (including history) in some detail.

Comment: Yes, there is a Frame control and a NavigationWindow in WPF which supports navigation. It works perfectcly when I navigate through the navigation bar of the window except it does return false for CanGoBack which I badly need it in my MVVM architecture.

Comment: I've tried the exact thing explained in that link as well. I'm really confused.

Comment: You read that whole thing in 3 minutes?

Comment: I've read it before I implement any navigation stuff in my project.

Comment: @user3530012 - Did you consider re-reading that link on the off-chance you missed an important detail the first time you read it?

Comment: Well, I'm re-reading it now.

Answer (score 0):

you simply just register the Window.Navigated event and when the event fire you will see CanGoBack is true